# Installing Google Cloud SDK, what is the path to the rc file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-mac-os-x

I downloaded the tar, and ran the install.sh

Next I got this message, however I don't see any rc / .rc file?

```
To update your SDK installation to the latest version [162.0.1], run: 
$ gcloud components update


Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable shell command 
completion?

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y                    

The Google Cloud SDK installer will now prompt you to update an rc 
file to bring the Google Cloud CLIs into your environment.

Enter a path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use 
[/Users/leongaban/.zshrc]:
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Leon, the Cloud SDK installer provides you an option to update your `$PATH` as well as install shell completion for commands in the Cloud SDK. This is done by adding few lines to your shell startup script (commonly known as a `rc` file).

- Since you selected `y` to go forward with this step, the installer asks for the location of the `rc` file (i.e. shell startup script).
- It has detected that you use `zsh` and hence it gives you the default option to update this file `/Users/leongaban/.zshrc`.
- If instead you are using `bash` you would have to specify something like `/Users/leongaban/.bashrc`

You could also select `n` in the previous step and update `$PATH` and/or shell completion manually too.

Comment: Ah yeah I see it in my zsh config `export GOOGLE_SDK_PATH="/Users/leongaban/projects/GoogleSDK"`

Comment: But should we leave it blank or do we need to input something? Currently on my end I do not have .zshrc file but I do use zsh shell as default hence I use .zprofile when adding PATHs.